# I found a box of game cards which when I was a kid, my friends gave me - is this writing style acceptable?

Tags: relative-clauses

The when-clauses below modify the main actions in the adjective clauses.

But can I reverse it and change their positions to the front, like the positions of the ones in bold in Example 2 and Example 4?

**Example 1:**

> He is one of the victims who the rescue team found **when they searched the woods**.

**Example 2:**

> He is one of the victims who **when the rescue team searched the woods**, they found.

**Example 3:**

> I found a box of game cards which my friends gave me **when I was a kid**.

**Example 4:**

> I found a box of game cards which **when I was a kid**, my friends gave me.

Answer (score 4):

They are technically all correct. The poet Robert Frost famously wrote this line, which has become a sort of aphorism:

> Home is the place where, when you have to go there, they have to take you in.

This example raises my next two points:

1. This usage is uncommon in natural speech. I would expect to see it in print only, or perhaps in a speech prepared for a public performance.
2. When such a long phrase/clause interrupts the normal word order, it works best with a comma on each side, not merely at the end.

Given the formal nature of this structure, I'd be inclined to use **whom** instead of **who** in your second example because it is an object, not a subject. Most readers would accept **who** without noticing a problem, but a few traditionalists might object.

For the same reason, I'd probably use **child** instead of **kid** in your fourth example.

I would not make these adjustments in your first and third examples, which sound more like spoken English.